# 1px difference in "votes" section of questions on main page

Tags: bug, design

"votes" section of question seems being higher than "answers" and "views" on Stack Overflow main page:

[image]

Comment: How ... do you even notice ...

Comment: I never noticed that, but now I can't unsee it.

Comment: It's a good thing I never use the homepage... otherwise this would infuriate me

Comment: I'm flagging this so a mod can see this. God, I hate the home screen now :)

Comment: Maybe ... intentional?

Comment: @bravemaster Encouraging to ↑ up-vote? Or downvote, to make the position even again ;)